# Is Wonder Woman's only weakness being bound by a man?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman

I know that Wonder Woman's only known weakness is being "bound by man". However:

- It's only being bound by a man??
- Does she have any other weaknesses?

Comment: It's varied over the years. I'm pretty sure there have been cases where she's been tied up by women and has been unable to escape. As for other weaknesses, she is not invulnerable, and has shown less resistance to piercing weapons than slashing and bludgeoning.

Comment: Even though I get what the question is asking (mostly), I strongly suggest the OP re-phrase the question so it's more clear.

Comment: @SeanDuggan in the 40s, when she was written, it was explicit that having *a man*  tie her hands took away all of her super powers, which I was I assume the OP is asking about.

Comment: One of the weaknesses was her being bound by her lasso specifically. Hoisted by her own petards so to speak

Comment: [Standard Female Grab Area](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StandardFemaleGrabArea)

Answer (score 34):

Being bound by man hasn't been a weakness of Wonder Woman's for a very long time. That dates back to the very early incarnations of wonder Woman, when she was basically just an excuse to show bondage in the comics. (Her creator was a big proponent of bondage.) That rather insane idea was tossed out with the start of the Modern Age in the 80s.

Originally, she had *two* weaknesses, both based around the fact that the bracelets she wore were "Bracelets of Submission". First, if a man managed to tie her bracelets together, she would lose all of her superpowers, exactly like Superman and kryptonite. Second, if her bracelets were ever lost or broken, she's go into an uncontrollable rage.

[image: Wonder Woman sobbing with her bracelets tied together. She thinks "My strength is gone - it is Aphrodite's law! When an Amazon girl permits a MAN to chain her Bracelets of Submission together she becomes weak as other women in a man-ruled world! Poor Steve - I've failed him!"] [image: Wonder Woman says "--an Amazon loses control-- over her own strength-- --and goes berserk!", and send a vehicle flying with a kick.]

Modern Age Wonder Woman had no specifically called-out weaknesses. About the closest she's come is that her super-human stamina and resistance to injury does not seem to apply to piercing weapons, like arrows or daggers; her enhanced healing does not work against such injuries. Note that she's not necessarily *weaker* to such injuries than a normal person, and she still has her other superpowers, she's just not *as immune* to piercing attacks than others. (Supposedly, this idea was George Pérez's attempt to make her immune to the average crook, whose bullets she could dodge, while putting her in real danger against super-villain class enemies.)

Post New-52 reboot, she hasn't even shown that much of a weakness; Batman has speculated that she has no real weaknesses aside from her relationship with Superman.

Comment: I don't recall where in the New 52 this is, but it was shown at one point that Batman keeps a set of suitcases containing some means of dealing with a superhero if he or she ever goes rogue. Superman's suitcase, for example, contains kryptonite, while Green Lantern's suitcase contains a Sinestro Corps ring, and there are others: one for each member of the Justice League. But it's stated outright that Wonder Woman's suitcase is empty: Batman has not been able to figure out anything to put in it.

Comment: Funny, one of the pre new 52 plan for WW was simply a hallucigenic solution and let her wear herself out.

Comment: @user16696 Was that Tower of Babel?

Answer (score 11):

That, um...depends on which version of her you are asking about.

In her original version, her creator believed that bondage was a key to a healthy relationship, and wrote this into her character. "As per Aphrodite's law, when an Amazon's bracelets are bound together by the actions of a man, she loses her powers." [ref](http://www.amazonarchives.com/ww229.htm)

This was still around as recently as the TV show in the 70s. However, this weakness has since been retconned out of existence. I think it may have even been lampshaded at some point, though I cannot remember the reference for that.

Now, (again, depending on which version you are asking about) she has lesser weaknesses. Earth Prime Wonder Woman has, according to Batman, 'no convenient weaknesses' and while she can suffer injury from piercing weapons (blades, bullets, etc) she has some level of resistance to that damage, preventing it from becoming life-threatening.

New Earth WW retains a higher degree of vulnerability to piercing weapons.

Neither of her modern incarnations have a 'convenient' weakness that shuts her powers down (like Superman and Kryptonite)

Answer (score 10):

Her original key weakness was *permitting* herself to be bound by a *man*. While this didn't always carry over the stories long run, it was absolutely key to the character Dr. Marston, an ardent feminist and practicing psychologist, was creating. His point was that women are not actually inferior to men (the standard assumption at the time and throughout much of history), they are oppressed. The only reason they are "weaker" is because they allow men to make them so.

From Wonder Woman's original origin story the Amazons were Greek women who had been bound by the wrists by the men, who at one point realized their power and broke free. They then moved to their own women-only island, where, in the absence of male oppression, they grew progressively stronger and longer lived. The unbound cuffs ("Bracelets of Submission") were still worn to remind them that allowing a man power over them/giving up their independence was what sapped them of their own power.

(Marston was probably not into bondage himself, but was using it as a symbol, although, as a psychologist, he seemed pretty solid on the "kinky doesn't make something wrong, abuse does" concept. He was, after all, in a "marriage" with two women, one the niece of Margret Sanger, a renowned outspoken feminist of the previous generation.)[ref](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/origin-story-wonder-woman-180952710)

Comment: Marston wasn't "into bondage" in the sense that he was a BDSM practitioner; he also wasn't a chauvanist (he was actually pretty feminist for his time.) He simply believed that *everyone*, male or female, would be happer and more productive if they were submissive to someone stronger than them.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can find someone who can simply overpower her with sheer brute force like Superman, Ares, or Darkseid to pound the crap out of her.

She might be vulnerable to telepathy, hypnosis, or drugs.

All her powers are based on magic. The DC encyclopedia says she gains power from physical contact with the Earth or any earth like substance since she was molded from clay. She's the new God of War in the new 52. And Hephaestus made her armor. One could exploit such things.

The Justice League cartoons said her armor actually gives her her powers, if really want to beat her... You see where I'm going.

Answer (score 0):

In the TV series with Lynda Carter if her gold belt which has the golden lasso is removed she becomes just like a regular person no super strenth .